# Trying to change a variable with an input text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I am trying to get an input text field to change a variable I have set up and then make a bunch of the movie clips I have set up for the variable.

here is the code I want to change

```
    var blue:MovieClip = new Blue  ;
```

I need to have Blue change to what is in the input field if that's possible

Comment: i tried   `var blue:MovieClip = new player1.text  ;` player1 is the input textfield instance name

Comment: How will text change a `MovieClip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't create a new class name based on a string (i.e. the value of a text field).

You'd have to create your classes initially:

```
var blue:MovieClip = new Blue();
var green:MovieClip = new Green();
...
```

Then use a switch to say:

```
switch(player1.text){
case 'blue' : 
  //load blue mc
  break;
case 'green' :
  // load green ms
  break;
}
```

The biggest issue here is that a text input can take any value.  You might be better off using a series of radio buttons that have predefined values.  Then you those with your switch.

Comment: I got that code to work but isnt quite what i wanted to have happen but i got something figured out to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of classes based off a String using [`getDefinitionByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29).

Example code:

```
function loadClip(string:String):MovieClip
{
    var type:Class = getDefinitionByName(string) as Class;
    var mc:MovieClip = new type();

    return mc;
}
```

Which you can then use with the value of `player1.text` to create different types of MovieClips that you have set up:

```
try
{
    var colorMc:MovieClip = loadClip(player.text);
}
catch(e:ReferenceError)
{
    trace(e);
}
```